# Wso2 ESB callout mediator return response to client

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I've setup a API on my ESB that makes a call to a Data service that returns data from the database this works but what I want to do now is return that data to the client/web browser and display it on screen.

My code for the API is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DatabaseTest" context="/dbtest">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <callout serviceURL="http://10.248.40.85:9764/services/TestDSS/operation1">
                <source type="envelope"/>
                <target key="response"/>
            </callout>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="output" expression="get-property('response')"/>
            </log>
            <header name="To" scope="default" action="remove"/>
            <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making the response inside the proxy service for get request you need to add this property after removing the `To` header.

```
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```

Comment: By adding the NO_ENTITY_BODY property when testing the service it now prompts me to download a file which is empty?. Is there any way to just return this data to the browser window?